# how to echo checkbox group?

Tags: php, html, css, xhtml

Can somebody help me? i cant echo my checkbox group with a multiple selection.
Every time i echo the checkbox group the only things show is the last box that Ive check.

here's my code

```
<?php
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$incharge = $_POST['incharge'];

if ($submit)
{
   echo $incharge;
}

?>

<table width="500" height="69">
      <tr>
        <td width="73"><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="incharge" value="1" id="responsible_0" />
          MNFA</label></td>
          <td width="72"><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="incharge" value="2" id="responsible_1" />
          HJB</label></td>
          <td width="70"><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="incharge" value="3" id="responsible_2" />
          JBG</label></td>
          <td width="75"><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="incharge" value="4" id="responsible_3" />
          MSG</label></td>
          <td width="275"><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="incharge" value="5" id="responsible_4" />
          MGR</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td height="33"><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="incharge" value="6" id="responsible_5" />
          AAP</label></td>
          <td><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="incharge" value="7" id="responsible_6" />
          EPM</label></td>
          <td><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="incharge" value="8" id="responsible_7" />
          SGA</label></td>
          <td><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="incharge" value="9" id="responsible_8" />
          JLL</label></td>
          <td><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="incharge" value="10" id="responsible_9" />
          AFM</label></td> 
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Thank you in advance.. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name attribute to:

```
name="incharge[]"
```

That will produce an array, $incharge.

Note that you won't be able to just echo that value; you will need to "print_r" or loop through it.

Comment: I have seen some websites that do not use the [] notation. The respective request variable appears several times in the request array. E.g. if two check boxes would be checked in the form above, the URL string (in case of a GET) would contain 'incharge' two times with different values.

Comment: Oh, a lot of tutorials out there on the web do not mention the [] notation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the "name" attribute of your "input" elements to indicate that it's an array by adding square brackets `[]` at the end. `$_POST['incharge']` will be an array instead of a string.

**Example**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="incharge[]" value="1" id="responsible_0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason only the last value is being sent is because all the checkboxes have the same name, thereby renaming them over and over. What you want is to assign all the checkboxes to an array, like so:

Change `name="incharge"` to `name="incharge[]"`

You'll then want to iterate it:

```
if ($submit)
{
    // PHP throws a fit if we try to loop a non-array
    if(is_array($incharge))
    {
        foreach($incharge as $val)
        {
            echo $val . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could just use print_r($incharge) to display the array.

Comment: Yep or var_dump, etc. Figured he wanted to echo it in his example so I showed him how to echo each entry in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_post['calculations'])
{
    $member = $_POST['member'];//get the total values in an array

    if(is_array($member))// confirm $member is an array
    {
        foreach($member as $names)
        {
            echo $names ."<br/>";//take the values 

        }
    }


<input type="checkbox" name="member[]" value="value1">
```